# Android studio 3.1 gives error on importing project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

My question is about when I updated android studio up to latest version of 3.1 and when  open a project then it gives me error and i try to invalidate caches and restart android studio but still error is not gone as shown below 
[image: Android studio screenshot]

Comment: some apps gradle version and android plugin version don't match with yours. So what you need to do, is open a working android project (one you already have). Goto file -> project settings -> project and note down gradle version and android gradle plugin version. Then browse to imported app (which has the problem) and update gradle version and android plugin versions. This will save you installation time. There are alternate methods also. This one is quick. Let me know if it fixes ur issue.

Comment: still showing same error @AmirDe

Comment: see the Logcat and paste the result, it will be easier to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SOLVED**

1. Click on **File** >> Close Project
2. Delete .idea folder in project Directory
3. Open Project again

and it works

Answer (score 0):

Go in the gradle settings check the global gradle option. if checked to offline then uncheck it and try reload the project

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the right SDK for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Check classpath in build.gradle file in Project folder .
It should be

```
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
```

and "distributionUrl" in gradle-wrapper.properties ( in path ProjectFolder/gradle/). It also  should be updated; like

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

the correct values for the Android 3.1 should be

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

}
```

and the distribution URL will be

```
 distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

then clean and rebuild it should work.
I did for few projects today

Comment: where i need to put distribution URL?

Comment: you can find in "yourprojectdirectory\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties"

Answer (score 0):

set Write permission to android folder